# running D3 code on DOM ready without jquery

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mamp

Following the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169370/d3-js-and-document-onready) SO question/answer, I put my D3 code below the html and inside a function that's executed `onload`, however, when I test this on my MAMP local server, D3 code is not executing. Note, if I run the `runD3code` in the console then the intended bar chart appears, but if I  included that code inside the `runD3code` function in index.html then the bar chart doesn't appear. I also note that including the D3 below the html is how the library author does it [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


    <style type="text/css">   
      .chart div {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>

  <body onload="runD3code()">
      <div class="chart">

      </div>
        <script src="./d3.js" charset="utf-8">
       <script>
       function runD3code() {
        console.log("not getting called");
         var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
           d3.select(".chart")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("div")
            .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
        }
        </script>

  </body>
```

Then, I even tried putting it in a [document ready equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery), but the D3 code still didn't run

```
       (function(){
    var tId = setInterval(function(){if(document.readyState == "complete") onComplete()},11);
    function onComplete(){
        clearInterval(tId);    

         var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
           d3.select(".chart")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("div")
            .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; });

        };
})()
```

Can you suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your html file is invalid. Too many bugs in syntax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">   
      .chart div {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <script src="./d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
       window.onload = function runD3code() {
        console.log("not getting called");
         var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
           d3.select(".chart")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("div")
            .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
        };
     </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html page does not work for me using a MAMP server

Comment: It does now, you had changed the name of the D3 file. Thanks