# jquery .ready() equivalent in d3js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

currently i am adding all javascript at HTML `<head>` after uglying as file & using these jquery functions to check document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {}); OR $(function() {});
```

is there any d3js equivalent to remove using of these jquery functions ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but here's a plain Javascript replacement for `$(document).ready()`: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701) which includes options to just relocate the script tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 i am looking to remove jquery from application but the only dependancy is $(function() {});

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169370/d3-js-and-document-onready

Comment: Then, my link is something you can use since it is a plain Javascript replacement for `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### A

You can simply put the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `body` tag.

#### B

you can add the `DOMContentLoaded` event and insert your d3js code inside.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
   /* Your D3.js here */
  });
```

#### Direct Answer

There is **no** equivalent to the jQuery function in the D3.js library, the snippet written above will work as well.

Answer (score 6):

There is no specific `d3` way but,

if your javascript is below any of the html elements then the dom is loaded before it starts executing the javascript.

Putting your javascript at the bottom of the body is usually good enough.
You can also use native `js` method which works in most of the browsers.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`selection.on()` docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#handling-events), any event type can be used in it, so

```js
d3.select(document).on("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... });
```

could be called the "d3 way".

However, note that whichever way you subscribe to `DOMContentLoaded`, it's **not equivalent** to `.ready()`:

> However, jQuery's `.ready()` method differs in an important and useful way: If the DOM becomes ready and the browser fires `DOMContentLoaded` before the code calls `.ready( handler )`, the function `handler` will still be executed. -- [source](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#:%7E:text=If%20the%20DOM%20becomes%20ready%20and%20the%20browser%20fires%20DOMContentLoaded%20before%20the%20code%20calls%20.ready(%20handler%20)%2C%20the%20function%20handler%20will%20still%20be%20executed.)